# CentOS: RVM and no package libyaml available

Tags: centos, rvm, package

I'm trying to install RVM on a CentOS host and it fails with this error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby: error while loading shared libraries: libruby.so.1.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Libraries missing for ruby-1.9.3-p194: libruby.so.1.9. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
Mounting remote ruby failed, trying to compile.
```

After some Googling it seems I need to manually install the libyaml package, to which the host says:

```
No package libyaml available.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See also [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882190/unable-to-resolve-ruby-error-missing-psych).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by piecing together others' attempts. I followed [these](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ablog.jeffcosta.com%2F2011%2F07%2F22%2Finstall-ruby-version-manager-rvm-on-centos-6%2F&oq=cache%3Ablog.jeffcosta.com%2F2011%2F07%2F22%2Finstall-ruby-version-manager-rvm-on-centos-6%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.2255j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) instructions, and despite getting an error that read:

```
Error running 'autoreconf -is --force', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p320/yaml/autoreconf.log
```

I managed to install both the `rake` gem and the `rails` gem.

Answer (score 6):

Try installing this using RVM :

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
```

It works on my CENTOS 6.3 VPS.

Comment: This installs `libyaml`, but not `libyaml-devel`. For that, it still returns "No package libyaml-devel available" for the defautlt CentOS repos.

Answer (score 3):

with the latest rvm (run `rvm get head`), libyaml is automatically fetched when installing Ruby (well, at least on 1.9.3).

You'll see if it has been installed by inspecting /usr/local as that's where rvm puts it...