# Unable to resolve Ruby error (missing psych)

Tags: ruby, installation, vps

Whenever I run something with Ruby on my server, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

I installed Ruby using RVM onto my VPS.

I’ve tried installing the package `libyaml` as per instructed in other issues on Stack Overflow, to no avail.

I’m not sure what type of system my VPS is running, but it doesn’t have the `apt-get` command. It does have `yum`…

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had this problem and installing libyaml didn't help. It turned out that libyaml-devel was needed by psych. I was on centos6 so I did this:

```
curl -O http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/centos/6/x86_64/RPMS/atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch.rpm

sudo  rpm -Uvh atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch.rpm

sudo yum install libyaml-devel

rvm reinstall 1.9.3-p194
```

Comment: When I run sudo `rpm -Uvh atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch.rpm`, I get: `warning: atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 5ebd2744
error: Failed dependencies:
 rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch
 rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch`

Comment: What OS? Could you run in a shell: uname -a
and post the output here please

Comment: If it is Fedora you are running, search rpm.pbone.net for: libyaml-devel fedora rpm - for your version. For example, Fedora 16 x86_64 will take you here http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17341900/dir/fedora_16/com/libyaml-devel-0.1.4-1.fc16.x86_64.rpm.html.

Comment: Linux server9987 2.6.32-042stab049.6 #1 SMP Mon Feb 6 19:17:43 MSK 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: ok - so its openvz server. Maybe I should not have pointed to the x86_64 repo. sorry. Seems you can get libyaml-devel for i386 in this repo: http://www6.atomicorp.com/channels/atomic/redhat/6/i386/RPMS/atomic-release-1.0-14.el6.art.noarch.rpm .

Comment: Running the above commands with that repo instead gives me exactly the same error as before (see above comment). Sorry if I seem like a n00b. Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: You have errors of unresolved dependencies that don't appear on my system - try to install those dependencies it asks for: FileDigests and PayloadIsXz. I have no idea what they are. If succeed, then install libyaml-devel, and then reinstall ruby. I just searched for libyaml-devel openvz and found some a link that suggests:
wget http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
-- then --
rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-0.5.2-2.el5.rf.i386.rpm
-- then -- yum install libyaml-devel ... sorry I can't try any of this  out.

Comment: Ran the commands you mentioned at the end of your comment and then reinstalled Ruby: `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`. Sorted! Thank you very, very much.

Comment: Complete installation process (CentOS 6.3, Ruby) https://gist.github.com/denispeplin/5011950

Answer (score 21):

I have to disagree with @JunaidKirkire in that I think you are running CentOS or Redhat 5 which uses a a very old version of Ruby by default and I think using RVM is a much better way to go.  I believe you will just need to compile libyaml from source with the following:

`rvm pkg install libyaml`

This will tell you the directory that it is compiling into, in my case, it is `/Users/ehowe/.rvm/usr`

You then need to recompile Ruby with the following option:

`rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=$directory_that_rvm_installed_libyaml_to`

So in my case, I would do:

`rvm install 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/Users/ehowe/.rvm/usr`

If you are running rvm as root, this will get installed into `/usr/local/rvm/usr`.  If you are running it as a user, as is recommended, it would be `/home/$user/.rvm/usr`

Comment: Does this look correct: `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4`. Or would it just be? `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/usr/local/rvm`?

Comment: After running `rvm pkg install libyaml` and then `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/usr/local/rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4`, I am still getting the `psych` warning.

Comment: You should just use `/usr/local/rvm/usr` as the path.I tested this and it worked.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you used the correct path?  I tested this on a clean CentOS 5.8 install and it worked for me.  Can you try it again and send me a gist with the complete output from start to finish?

Comment: http://hastebin.com/mewexusidu.vbs — example of the error immediately after reinstalling at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/442150/how-to-fix-ruby-installation-is-missing-psych-for-yaml-output-on-centos

Comment: Sorted my problem on CentOS 6.3 using `--with-libyaml-dir=/home/$user/.rvm/usr`. Thanks!

Comment: I had same issue on Ubuntu and this solved it for me. Many other suggestions did not work. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

On a RHEL based distro such as CentOS 6.x you need to add another yum repository such as EPEL which contain the libyaml-devel package.

[Keys](https://fedoraproject.org/keys) for EPEL or [download](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/)
[RPM](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/) for EPEL

More info:

- [CentOS - Additional Resources](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories)
- [Fedora Project: EPEL Howto](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F)

Would also suggest the use of [yum-plugin-priorities](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities)

#### Add EPEL Yum Repository

```
rpm --import http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
rpm -Kih http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

#### Install libyaml-devel via yum

```
yum -y install libyaml-devel
```

#### Packages

```
Dependencies Resolved

====================================================================================
 Package                       Arch         Version           Repository       Size
====================================================================================
Installing:
 libyaml-devel                 x86_64       0.1.3-1.el6       epel             84 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libyaml                       x86_64       0.1.3-1.el6       epel             52 k

Transaction Summary
====================================================================================
Install       2 Package(s)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be solved by installing `libyaml`. Below are the corresponding packages for the most popular distributions:

- Fedora `libyaml`
- Ubuntu and other Debian based `libyaml-dev`
- Some other like CentOS `libyaml-devel`

and also you should install the following to avoid similar problems in future:

```
ruby-devel libxml2 libxml2-devel libxslt libxslt-devel
```

Comment: “No package libyaml available.”

Comment: yes it should solve the problem. and if it does, please tick it as an answer :)

Comment: libyaml installed with `rvm pkg`, then I re-installed Ruby 1.9.3 with `rvm`. Still the same problem.

Comment: Tried installing `libyaml-devel` as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/12919013/1082754. Couldn’t get the install to work, however – and it’s not in Yum.

Comment: try apt-get install pkg_name if its ubuntu, if u cant find, try apt-get search pkg_name

Comment: I don’t have the `apt-get` command. Running Fedora, Centos 5.8.

Comment: If you are using fedora u must use sudo yum install pkg_name

Comment: It’s not solved, sorry. See comments in other answers for trouble I’m having with yum.

Answer (score 1):

In case people still hit this, I fixed it using the new autolibs feature in RVM, which automatically installs dependencies using your homebrew libraries (check out `rvm help autolibs` for info.)

`rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --autolibs=2`

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be working on Fedora.  Check the official Ruby website for instructions on installing on Fedora.

Try this link too http://sraji.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/how-to-install-ruby-on-fedora-14/

Comment: How do I install rubygems with that?

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh: Rubygems come installed by default when you install Ruby.

Comment: `ruby -v` // ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [i386-linux]. `gem` // bash: gem: command not found

Comment: @OliverJosephAsh try this link http://www.technetra.com/2009/04/22/howto-setting-up-ruby-on-rails-for-fedora-10-and-11/

Follow the above instructions and you will be fine.  Good luck.

Comment: Is there anyway I can find out what the latest version of rubygems is that will work with ruby 1.8.5? Or can I get yum to install 1.9.3 in any way?

Comment: What version of Fedora/Redhat/CentOS is your VPS running?  You can find out with `cat /etc/redhat-release`

Comment: CentOS release 5.8 (Final) (Thank you)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same libyaml issue with CentOS 6.2

Doing...

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-libyaml-dir=/usr/local/rvm/usr
```

Fixed it for me.

(thanks to @[Eugene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256785/eugene))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Redhat machine has a valid subscription:

```
# subscription-manager list 

+-------------------------------------------+
    Installed Product Status
+-------------------------------------------+
Product Name:   Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server
Product ID:     69
Version:        7.1
Arch:           x86_64
Status:         Subscribed
Status Details: 
Starts:         06/13/2014
Ends:           06/12/2015
```

Status must say "Subscribed".  If not, then suffer through getting a login and maybe purchasing a subscription at  https://access.redhat.com/management/consumers.

When that's done, run

```
# subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms
```

then libyaml-devel will install OK.