# Please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

libyaml warning doesn't go away, even if you install libyaml

```
gem install bundler
/home/ec2-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top  (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Fetching: bundler-1.3.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.4
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First remove any previous docs of yaml by

```
cd .rvm/src
sudo rm -rf yaml*
```

Then you can do rest of the install by -

`rvm pkg install libyaml`

P.S You will need to reinstall ruby after this.

---

**UPDATE:** If `rvm pkg` seems to be deprecated. You can compile a source on your own. All you 
gotta do is download the latest version of libyaml  from  http://pyyaml.org/download/libyaml/

```
tar zxf yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz
cd yaml-0.1.4
./configure
make
make install
```

---

**UPDATE2:** BTW, you could still use rvm pkg and/or when reinstalling ruby make sure to enbale autolibs by 
`\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enable`

Comment: For that didn't work. I even reinstalled rvm, turnend on autolibs etc. Finally manually downloaded and installed libyaml (like above) and installed the ruby with the libyaml option (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12882906/651651).

Answer (score 25):

A friend of mine had a similar problem on his mac.

`brew install libyaml`

ended up working for us and we were able to avoid a reinstall of ruby.

Comment: This worked for 2 issues I was experiencing. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me without needing to reinstall Ruby. In my case, `brew install libyaml` did nothing since it was already installed, but `brew reinstall libyaml` did the trick.

Comment: You should add a soultion for every platform not only MAC

Comment: @disooqi No he doesn't, he doesn't have to provide solutions for all platforms because they are sharing their experience with a Mac and he is possibly limited to that. It's up to the reader to adapt the information to their own platform and seek help from others in the community if needed. Other users would improve this collection of answers here to satisfy your requirement.

Answer (score 15):

If using homebrew, a temporary fix that worked for me was to run:

```
brew unlink libyaml && brew link libyaml
```

plus you may also need to run:

```
brew unlink openssl && brew link --force openssl
```

See this issue thread for more details: https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2689

Comment: After trying everything under the sun, this is what solve my issue.