# Whenever I use the word "require" I get an error and I also get an error if I try to use relative_require

Tags: ruby, require

I tried to solve my error by using `relative_require`, but this also does not seem to work. When I use the word `require` to run the following code:

```
APP_ROOT = File.dirname(__FILE__)

require File.join(APP_ROOT, 'lib')
require 'guide'

guide = Guide.new('restaurants.txt')
guide.launch!
```

I get this error:

```
/Users/catherinealvarado/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ./lib (LoadError)
    from /Users/catherinealvarado/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from init.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

I tried to solve this error by doing `gem install netrc && gem install heroku-api` shown in the link below, but I get an error stating that I should install libyaml and reinstall ruby. 
https://github.com/gregburek/heroku-buildpack-toolbelt/issues/5

I then tried to install libyaml and reinstall ruby, but I get more errors. I followed the instructions on the link below:

[Please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738883/please-install-libyaml-and-reinstall-your-ruby)

I am new to ruby and I have been stuck on this bug for quite some time. I don't think I have any syntax errors in the file I am trying to load. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked whether APP_ROOT is resulting to correct path?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `require_relative` rather than `relative_require`?

Comment: Do you really have a file called lib.rb in APP_ROOT?

Comment: I don't know how to locate my APP_ROOT or what it is. I also don't know how to check if I have lib.rb in it.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file located that you're running this from?  The root?

If so you, you can just do:

`require_relative 'lib/guide'`

For me, I'm almost always requiring outside files from my spec director, so my calls look like this:

```
require_relative '../lib/guide'
```

Comment: I tried to do require_relative 'lib/guide' but I get the error: Catherines-MacBookAir:food_finder catherinealvarado$ ruby init.rb 
init.rb:11:in `require_relative': cannot load such file -- /Users/catherinealvarado/Desktop/food_finder/lib (LoadError)
 from init.rb:11:in `<main>'

Comment: Can you run ls in your terminal and show me the output?

Comment: When I run ls I get the following:

Comment: Catherines-MacBookAir:food_finder catherinealvarado$ ls
init.rb lib         [note* inside the lib folder I have guide.rb and   restaurant.rb ]

Comment: Catherines-MacBookAir:lib catherinealvarado$ ls
guide.rb restaurant.rb

Comment: I was able to solve my bug. Thank you all for the suggestions.